# get first message in email

Tags: php, email, parsing, mandrill

I have an interesting problem that I can't seem to figure out properly and need a little guidance (if you kindly would).

I am converting an SMS message over to an email to be sent, and before I send the message via email, I add the following to the message:

```
  $sending_message = $message . '<br>-------------- Reply above this line --------------';
```

Because the format is being sent out via html, it renders properly in gmail as it should. Now, here's where the issue comes in. A user should be able to reply to that message via gmail and it gets sent back to another php script that allows it to convert back to an sms message. Whether I use

```
$message = $content[0]->msg->text;
or
$message = $content[0]->msg->html;
```

I get something that looks like this:

```
Test

On Tue, Jan 13, 2015 at 10:42 PM, 10digit#@email.mydomain.com <
10digit#@email.mydomain.com> wrote:

> kiojihiuhygyutfuy
>
```

I know I'm possibly in for a nightmare of a time trying to get just the response text, but what's the best approach?

I have tried

```
    $temp_message = explode('-------------- Reply', $message);

    $message = trim($temp_message[0]);
```

Which nets me the results that you see above. So I am a bit baffled as to how I can get the last message, or first message in the email being parsed. Any insight is appreciated on how to go about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this library will help you massively...

https://github.com/willdurand/EmailReplyParser

You can then get the content you need using:

```
use EmailReplyParser\Parser\EmailParser;

$email = (new EmailParser())->parse($emailContent);
$content = $email->getVisibleText();
```

Please note: I haven't actually tried this yet myself, but have done some research as I will be very soon. But I hope this helps you get what you need :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it. It is really good. https://github.com/willdurand/EmailReplyParser

```
    require_once 'autoload_EmailReplyParser.php';
    $email = new \EmailReplyParser\EmailReplyParser();
    $reply = $email->read($this->body);            
    //Buscamos teléfono en fragmento Signature
    $fragments = $reply->getFragments();
    foreach ($fragments as $fragment) {
        if ($fragment->isSignature()) {
            if (preg_match('~(tfno|tlfno|tlf|teléfono|phone)(.*?)\n~si',$fragment->getContent(), $tfno)) {
                $this->telefono = $tfno[0];
                break;
            }
        } 
    }
    //Establecemos mensaje visible (sin Hidden, sin Quoted y sin Signature)
    $this->mensajelimpio = $reply->getVisibleText();
    $this->mensajelimpio = preg_replace('~On(.*?)wrote:(.*?)$~si', '', $this->mensajelimpio);
```